# Live editing offline WordPress installation in PhpStorm

Tags: wordpress, xampp, phpstorm

I was wondering if it was possible to set up live editing of an offline WordPress installation using PhpStorm.

I have configured XAMPP and an offline version of WordPress, and I have live editing working. However, I can't figure out how to marry the two. I'm not experienced enough to tell if this is technically impossible, if so I would like a hint.

Comment: Do you have an example app running or example code to show where you're having issues?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "live editing"? IDE has "live edit" feature: that's basically a debug session with Live Edit plugin installed. Please see following article: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html